# netsh wlan show profile name=profile name key=clear is not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd

i used netsh wlan show profile name=prof name key=clear.Then i received message as 'There is no such wireless interface on the system'.But netsh wlan show profiles,netsh wlan show drivers commands are working well.how can i fix this problem? please help me.

Comment: If the profile name includes a space character, put it in quotes. "

Comment: oh yes! thank my friend its a mistake..

Answer (score 7):

If the profile name includes a space character, then it must be quoted.

```
netsh wlan show profile name="prof name" key=clear
```

Answer (score 2):

You should run command prompt as an Administrator.